# wait is not working but thread.sleep is working, also not throwing exception in selenium

Tags: selenium

```
//Thread.sleep(300);

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        WebDriverWait wait3 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
        wait3.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='toggleNav']/li[2]/a")));
        WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='toggleNav']/li[2]/a"));
        action.moveToElement(we).perform();

WebDriverWait wait4 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
        wait4.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='toggleNav']/li[2]/ul/li[3]/a")));
        WebElement we1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='toggleNav']/li[2]/ul/li[3]/a"));
        action.moveToElement(we1).click().build().perform();
```

With thread.sleep it works fine, but when used wait its not performing actions and also not throwing any element not found exceptions...

FYI used Java script too, in this case as well its not working when thread.sleep is commented

//Thread.sleep(300);

```
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);

    WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='toggleNav']/li[2]/a"));
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", we);
//  action.moveToElement(we).perform();


    WebElement we1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='toggleNav']/li[2]/ul/li[3]/a"));
    JavascriptExecutor executor1 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor1.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", we1);
    //action.moveToElement(we1).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: According to Javadoc of [`ExpectedConditions#presenceOfElementLocated(By)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-), this method checks that an element is present on the DOM of a page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is visible: an invisible element cannot be clicked. Did you try to replace the expected condition by `visibilityOfElementLocated(By)`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By....)
```

use

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By....)
```

This way you are waiting for the found element to be clickable before proceeding.